# Autoscaling the y axis when using rangeslider in Plotly

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I'm following the `rangeslider` example on the Plotly website: https://plot.ly/python/range-slider/

Is there a way to automatically (or even manually) rescale the y axis as the x range changes? For example, if the date range in the example above is set between Nov 2008 - April 2009, how can we automatically rescale the y axis to a more appropriate range to see the features in the data better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is no according to [this answer from the devs](http://community.plot.ly/t/autoscaling-the-y-axis-when-using-rangeslider/1456):

> Not at the moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2018, and I'm also having difficulty finding a concise solution to this, but here's a potential workaround posted on the plotly community site using  a FigureWidget:

https://community.plot.ly/t/y-axis-autoscaling-with-x-range-sliders/10245/3